# Status attribute for external group membership

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have G-Suite group containing external users (from gmail.com). When I call [Get all members API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#get_all_members), until 2018-12-17 google returns status attribute for all members, but now it's empty for external users:

```
{
   "kind": "admin#directory#member",
   "etag": "",
   "id": "1234",
   "email": "user@internal.domain",
   "role": "MEMBER",
   "type": "USER",
   "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
   "kind": "admin#directory#member",
   "etag": "",
   "id": "4321",
   "email": "some+user@gmail.com",
   "role": "MEMBER",
   "type": "USER"
}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members#resource) says nothing if status is mandatory attribute or not.

Can you please explain how to get all active members of certain group?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the [Members: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) API method instead?

Perhaps also try setting the flag for `includeDerivedMembership` to `true` (defaults to `false`)

Comment: Sorry I did mistake in API link. I use same API as you describe

Comment: And of course it did't work also with includeDerivedMembership = true